# Multiple Time Series Impact

Tags: time-series, optimization

I have a marketing business question where the objective is to learn from my historical data to deduce the best marketing strategy.

- Input (Leading Indicator)= For each year I have multiple monthly time series describing marketing budgets for each channel (TV, Radio...). This means I have in total n(number of years)*c(number of channels) time series.
- Input (Indicator of Interest)= Annual Share Of Market

My objective finally is to search for the optimal annual strategy that enhances SOM(Share Of Market) and what channels (time series) are impacting positively the SOM.

What algorithms you may suggest to me, please?